# Javascript scoping for object

Tags: javascript

I get that everything in Javascript is an object, but how is possible to declare one variable in one scope; I mean merely as a variable and suddenly start using it as an object assigning some properties "INSIDE" other functions. How does scoping for this case work?

https://github.com/ariya/esprima/blob/master/esprima.js

In this code, the **extra** variable is only declared without being given any properties:

```
var Token,
    extra;
```

And suddenly it starts being used by object as follows:

```
function addComment(type, value, start, end, loc) {
    var comment, attacher;

    assert(typeof start === 'number', 'Comment must have valid position');

    // Because the way the actual token is scanned, often the comments
    // (if any) are skipped twice during the lexical analysis.
    // Thus, we need to skip adding a comment if the comment array already
    // handled it.
    if (state.lastCommentStart >= start) {
        return;
    }
    state.lastCommentStart = start;

    comment = {
        type: type,
        value: value
    };
    if (extra.range) {
        comment.range = [start, end];
    }
    if (extra.loc) {
        comment.loc = loc;
    }
    extra.comments.push(comment);

    if (extra.attachComment) {
        attacher = {
            comment: comment,
            leading: null,
            trailing: null,
            range: [start, end]
        };
        extra.pendingComments.push(attacher);
    }
}
```

The closest example that I can get for this extra to be initiated as object is from the following function:

```
function tokenize(code, options) {
    var toString,
        token,
        tokens;

    toString = String;
    if (typeof code !== 'string' && !(code instanceof String)) {
        code = toString(code);
    }

    delegate = SyntaxTreeDelegate;
    source = code;
    index = 0;
    lineNumber = (source.length > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    lineStart = 0;
    length = source.length;
    lookahead = null;
    state = {
        allowIn: true,
        labelSet: {},
        inFunctionBody: false,
        inIteration: false,
        inSwitch: false,
        lastCommentStart: -1
    };

    extra = {};

    // Options matching.
    options = options || {};

    // Of course we collect tokens here.
    options.tokens = true;
    extra.tokens = [];
    extra.tokenize = true;
    // The following two fields are necessary to compute the Regex tokens.
    extra.openParenToken = -1;
    extra.openCurlyToken = -1;

    extra.range = (typeof options.range === 'boolean') && options.range;
    extra.loc = (typeof options.loc === 'boolean') && options.loc;

    if (typeof options.comment === 'boolean' && options.comment) {
        extra.comments = [];
    }
    if (typeof options.tolerant === 'boolean' && options.tolerant) {
        extra.errors = [];
    }

    if (length > 0) {
        if (typeof source[0] === 'undefined') {
            // Try first to convert to a string. This is good as fast path
            // for old IE which understands string indexing for string
            // literals only and not for string object.
            if (code instanceof String) {
                source = code.valueOf();
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        peek();
        if (lookahead.type === Token.EOF) {
            return extra.tokens;
        }

        token = lex();
        while (lookahead.type !== Token.EOF) {
            try {
                token = lex();
            } catch (lexError) {
                token = lookahead;
                if (extra.errors) {
                    extra.errors.push(lexError);
                    // We have to break on the first error
                    // to avoid infinite loops.
                    break;
                } else {
                    throw lexError;
                }
            }
        }

        filterTokenLocation();
        tokens = extra.tokens;
        if (typeof extra.comments !== 'undefined') {
            tokens.comments = extra.comments;
        }
        if (typeof extra.errors !== 'undefined') {
            tokens.errors = extra.errors;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        extra = {};
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

But still it is only inside this function, not in the same scope as

```
var Token,
    extra;
```

How is it possible just to declare a variable and only instantiate the properties inside a function? How is it shared between different scopes? Once given the properties in one function, is it shared to other scopes such as another scope in another function? So confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Line #3658](https://github.com/ariya/esprima/blob/master/esprima.js#L3658) sets it to an empty object:

```
extra = {};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But https://github.com/ariya/esprima/blob/master/esprima.js#L3632 is still  inside the function tokenize. How is the assignment applying to outer scope?

Comment: @MaynardEPSILON: `tokenize` itself is inside the function where `extra` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Scoping has to do with the matching of identifiers (i.e. names) to the what they refer to.  For an object created in one scope to be accessed from another, you merely need to have a name in each refer to the same thing (for example, by returning an object created in a function to its caller and having the caller assign it to a variable whose name is in its scope).